# Error While Attempting to docker-compose a Postgres Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

`docker/postgres/Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:14.5-alpine

WORKDIR /app
```

`docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
#    image: postgres:14.5-alpine
    build: docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: docker/postgres/.env
```

FWIW, `docker/postgres/.env` looks like this:

```
POSTGRES_USER=my_postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=users
```

When I try to `% docker compose up`, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "postgres": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

Note that when I compose with the image instead of the build, everything works fine. What's the issue?

Comment: If you specify `build` you must indicate a folder, [see doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build). Remove Dockerfile from `build`. Write `build: docker/postgres` or `dockerfile: docker/postgres/Dockerfile`

Comment: @Max I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: docker/postgres/.env
```

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Sure, because you didn't kill or recreate container. After you changed the service name to "db", it created new container with "db" instead "postgres" in container name.

Comment: No, I did kill the container before rerunning docker compose

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: I deleted the containers (and the images, and the volumes) on the docker desktop on the UI

Comment: no wait, @Slava Kuravsky, you are right. I went `% docker prune -a` and then also deleted all the volumes, and things work fine with `postgres` under `services`.

Comment: Better to check for containers with "docker ps -a" and remove them with "docker rm -f name"

Comment: can you give a crack at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071682/creating-postgres-table-in-docker?

Comment: I didn't quite go with this version of the `docker-file`, but this works too. Thanks for your help. Accepted.